# Getting the Time Zone (just the timezone) using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, timezone

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to get the PC's Time Zone using Angular. I just need the timezone because I need to format it in ('+H:MM').

I understand Angular only formats it one way ('+HHMM'), so I want to store this Time Zone and put in a string that I can then manipulate later.

Also I don't want to use plugins and/or libraries, if possible.

Comment: Just to clarify, Jeremy has answered the question in your question title, and thegio has answered the question in your question description. Because "Time Zone" !== "Time Zone Offset". Example of a time zone is ""Central European Standard Time"" - the distinction from "Offset" is important, because it's not a 1-to-1 mapping, and it's impossible to map directly from one to the other without additional data. A TimeZone can have different offsets for different dates (daylight savings) and a Time Zone Offset - even with a known date - can correspond to multiple possible TIme Zones.

Comment: (To unambiguously map a stored local appointment date that lies in the future, to its expected UTC date - taking into consideration the possibility of future changes to time zones and political borders etc - you need GPS coordinates. Google has one such API where you can query what the offset of a location is/was at a given date.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use Momentjs:

http://momentjs.com

[Momentjs Formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

```
var from = new Date();
var date = moment(from).format('Z'); //ZZ

alert(date);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nhp2ggng/)

Or you can perform a regular expression on the Date:

```
var from = new Date();
var res = from.toString().match(/[\+,\-](\d{4})\s/g);
alert(res);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1khn914f/)

But I'm not sure it is very robust.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think the plain javascript will have to do since I don't want to use momentsjs

Comment: This does not get the time zone. This gets the offset from UTC. There is no way to get a user's timezone from the browser, even with moment. The best you can do is use a library that guesses the user timezone. Jstz and moment timezone both implement this sort of functionality. I would recommend reading the tag wiki for time zone for more information.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
let timeZone;
if (typeof Intl === 'object' && typeof Intl.DateTimeFormat === 'function') {
  timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
  console.log({ timeZone });
}
```

Comment: This answer was what I wanted -> output: Europe/Berlin (if you remove the curly braces in the console.log)

Answer (score 1):

Might be late answer but just adding in case if it helps someone else.
moment-timezone package allows you can guess at the local time zone,
Install **moment-timezone** using:

*npm i moment-timezone -- save*

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

const timezone = moment.tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('z');
console.log(timezone); // eg: PST
```

This is ok, but be aware that:

1. It's just a guess. It might guess wrong.
2. If it does guess wrong, there's still a possibility that the abbreviation could be correct, as many similar time zones will use the same abbreviations, such as how Europe/Paris and Europe/Berlin both use CET and CEST.
3. However, there's no guarantees. If it guesses wrong, you might
   present the wrong abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

if you need get internet time use this site

http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json